# identify files with non-ASCII or non-printable characters in file name

Tags: bash, shell, find, filenames, character-encoding

In a directory size 80GB with approximately 700,000 files, there are some file names with non-English characters in the file name. Other than trawling through the file list  laboriously is there:

- An easy way to list or otherwise identify these file names?
- A way to generate printable non-English language characters - those characters that are not listed in the printable range of `man ascii` (so I can test that these files are being identified)?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Assuming that "foreign" means "not an ASCII character", then you can use `find` with a pattern to find all files not having printable ASCII characters in their names:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[! -~]*'
```

(The space is the first printable character listed on http://www.asciitable.com/, `~` is the last.)

The hint for `LC_ALL=C` is required (actually, `LC_CTYPE=C` and `LC_COLLATE=C`), otherwise the character range is interpreted incorrectly. See also the manual page `glob(7)`. Since `LC_ALL=C` causes `find` to interpret strings as ASCII, it will print multi-byte characters (such as `π`) as question marks. To fix this, pipe to some program (e.g. `cat`) or redirect to file.

Instead of specifying character ranges, `[:print:]` can also be used to select "printable characters". Be sure to set the C locale or you get quite (seemingly) arbitrary behavior.

Example:

```
$ touch $(printf '\u03c0') "$(printf 'x\ty')"
$ ls -F
dir/  foo  foo.c  xrestop-0.4/  xrestop-0.4.tar.gz  π
$ find -name '*[! -~]*'       # this is broken (LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8)
./x?y
./dir
./π
... (a lot more)
./foo.c
$ LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[! -~]*'
./x?y
./??
$ LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[! -~]*' | cat
./x y
./π
$ LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[![:print:]]*' | cat
./x y
./π
```

Comment: Be aware that you have file names that are using foreign character sets that are incompatible with UTF-8 or ASCII. In those cases, you may see question marks instead of characters.

Comment: +1, but I would use `LC_ALL=C` instead of `LC_COLLATE=C` as it's doesn't make much sense to set LC_COLLATE to C without setting `LC_CTYPE` and to make sure it still works even when the LC_ALL variable is in the environment.

Comment: If `SPC` is _printable_, then what about `TAB` and `LF` which are also typically found in text files?

Comment: Thanks - this found six files, which had long hyphen, short hyphen and a variant of single quote. These had all originated from MS Word. No difference in the files listed between LC_ALL and LC_COLLATE. LC_COLLATE displayed the non-ASCII chars correctly whereas LC_ALL displayed ??? instead. Excellent answer!

Comment: @suspectus I updated by answer based on suggestions from Stephane. For `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE`, see also the `find(1)` manpage.

Answer (score 5):

If you translate each file name using `tr -d '[\200-\377]'` and compare it with the original name, then any file names that have special characters will not be the same.

(The above assuming that you mean non-ASCII with foreign)

Comment: That also removes `[` and `]` in most `tr` implementations.

Comment: Yes - it did remove `[` and `]` on my system.

Comment: +1 - the solution did find all the (six) file names with non ASCII symbols (in addition to the `[` and `]`s). thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tr` to delete any foreign character from a filename and
compare the result with the original filename to see if it contained
foreign characters.

```
find . -type f > filenames
while read filename; do
      stripped="$(printf '%s\n' "$filename" | tr -d -C '[[:alnum:]][[:space:]][[:punct:]]')"
      test "$filename" = "$stripped" || printf '%s\n' "$filename"; 
done < filenames
```

Comment: that is a nice extension to my answer, but it is too simple, file names can have newlines in them and then your script will not work

Comment: If you want to post-process `find` output, use NUL-terminated output/input as shown in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/702461/47108).

Answer (score 2):

[The accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109753/1820) is helpful, but if your filenames are already in the encoding specified in `LANG`/`LC_CTYPE`, it's better to just do:

```bsh
LC_COLLATE=C find . -name '*[! -~]*'
```

Character classes are affected by `LC_CTYPE`, but the above command does not use character classes, only ranges, so `LC_CTYPE` just prevents the unusual characters from being replaced by question marks.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are usable, but the following gives better visual identification of the exact "offending" characters:

```bash
find | GREP_COLORS='mt=05;07;31' LC_ALL=C grep --color=always -E '[^[:print:]]'
```

Comment: `find | LC_ALL=C ack --color-match="blink reverse red" '[^[:print:]]'` also works, if you have `ack` installed.